# Manipulating a value within several layers of monads

Tags: haskell

My goal is to pull out `numVal4` from `Employment` -- but doing it from the level of the `MyEmployment` value.

```
data Employment = Employment
   { textVal1 :: Text
   , textVal2 :: Text
   , textVal3 :: Text
   , numVal4 :: Money }

data MyEmployment = MyEmployment Person Employment

MyEmployment (Person "Me") (Employment "This" "is a" "test" 55)

fmap . fmap (fromInteger (Employment _ _ _ x)) MyEmployment
```

EDIT:

I should have bee more specific.  I need to access the value from within a DMap.  The actual code looks like something closer to this:

```
thing = dmap ! (Some_Function . Some_OtherFunction $ MyEmployment)
```

And I need to get the numeric value from inside of `Employment`, with some kind of wrapper like:

```
thing = fmap (fromIntegral (Employment _ _ _ x)) (dmap ! (Some_Function . Some_OtherFunction $ MyEmployment)
```

Comment: Where is the monad? Please show a complete example that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please make a complete, compiling example with all data structures and a syntactically valid definition of the value into which you want to zoom in.

Comment: What is Person, and what is `MyEmployment` supposed to be? You have several syntax issues here. Capitalization matters in Haskell; you need to distinguish between types, constructors, and functions more clearly.

Comment: Sure -- this is pseudocode that I wrote just to communicate what I'm trying to get inside.

Comment: @reallymemorable Could you fix it please? Right now a lot of people here - including me - are quite confused about exactly what it is you're trying to communicate.

Comment: What is `dmap`? `fmap` seems irrelevant, because you don't have any functors, let alone monads. All your types (`Employment`, `Person`, `MyEmployment`) have kind `*`, not `* -> *` required for a functor.

Comment: Just chatting with @reallymemorable on slack and he's working on his actual question

Answer (score 3):

Apart from all the syntax issues, I think what you are trying to do is the following.

This is how you declare a data type:

```
data Employment = Employment
    { textVal1 :: Text
    , textVal2 :: Text
    , textVal3 :: Text
    , numVal4  :: Money }
```

Note the `::`s which are not `=`, and note the indentation.

`MyEmployment` seems to be a data type and by `MyEmployment :: Person Employment` I think you in fact mean

```
data MyEmployment = MyEmployment Person Employment
```

In this setting then, If you want to take a value of type `MyEmployment`, and apply a function to the `numVal4` field of the `Employment` field, record syntax allows you to write:

```
foo :: (Money -> Money) -> MyEmployment -> MyEmployment
foo f (MyEmployment p e@(Employment {numVal4 = nv}))
        = MyEmployment p ( e {numVal4 = f nv})
```